# Есть ли готовые решения для лексического/синтаксического анализатора?

Tags: синтаксический-анализ, лексический-анализатор, транслятор

У меня задача из входного текстового файла выделить структуры данных и записать их в базу данных. Текст в текстовом файле представляет из себя некий формальный язык.
Я начал искать инфу что да как, понял что нужно выделить лексемы сначала, потом провести синтаксический анализ. Как я понял все это делается с помощью конечного автомата.
Например `var number = 20`, занести в таблицу "Переменные" запись с названием и со значением.
Правильно ли я понимаю порядок действий? :

1. Написать лексический анализатор
2. Синтаксический анализатор

Есть ли готовые средства для этого (слышал что то про генераторы лексических анализаторов, но пока не смотрел)?

Comment: Можно какой-нибудь готовый встраиваемый язык использовать, типа Lua

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Разумеется есть: **ANTLR, yacc/bison + lex/flex**. Но задача реализации языка, пусть даже и примитивного, не так проста как может показаться. Если опыта нет, придётся потратить значительное время, чтобы углубиться в тему.

P.S.: Если задача только хранить/читать/писать данные, может имеет смысл выбрать другой способ их представления: XML, JSON, CSV и прочее.

Comment: Плюсую, к списку форматов я бы еще добавил TOML и YAML - они более удобны для редактирования человеком

Comment: Есть Tamsin еще, если для код-гольфа.

Comment: Язык как таковой уже есть, описана грамматика языка в форме Бэкуса-Наура. Сейчас именно вопрос интересует как транслировать этот текст в структуры данных и сохранять их в БД. Спасибо, я обязательно посмотрю инструменты, которые вы отправили.

Comment: А у вас есть опыт работы с ANTLR4?

Comment: @Андрей, нет.____